# how to select each individual id from an object array with javascript array methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm fetching data that gives me an object array of product information:

```
productInfo = [
  {ProductID: '1', ProductName: 'crayons', CategoryID: '1', Price: '10', Stock: '10'},
  ...etc
]
```

I am trying to get each specific ProductID when I click on the edit button, in order to edit each specific product.
I want to try two different methods (as you may see below).
either set productId state into the clicked value, or set the defaultValue of the input as the selected specified ID.

```
                              Product ID: <input 
                                            placeholder="enter product name" 
                                            type="text" 
                                            // onChange={({target}) => setProductId(target.value)}
                                            defaultValue={productId} 
                                            />
                            Product Name: <input 
                                            placeholder="enter product name" 
                                            type="text" 
                                            onChange={({target}) => setProduct(target.value)} 
                                            value={product} 
                                            />
                            Category ID: <input 
                                            placeholder="enter category id" 
                                            type="text" 
                                            onChange={({target}) => setCatId(target.value)} 
                                            value={catId} 
                                            />
                            Price: <input 
                                            placeholder="enter price" 
                                            type="text" 
                                            onChange={({target}) => setPrice(target.value)} 
                                            value={price} 
                                            />
                            Stock: <input 
                                            placeholder="enter stock amount" 
                                            type="text" 
                                            onChange={({target}) => setStock(target.value)} 
                                            value={stock} 
                                            />
                            <button 
                                disabled={invalid}
                                style={invalid ? {cursor: 'not-allowed'} : {cursor: "pointer"} } 
                                type="submit" 
                                onClick={() => {
                                updateProduct(productId,product, catId, price, stock)
                            }}> Update </button>
```

I am having a difficult time trying to grab the specific id of each product.
I can easily get all of the IDs, but not each individual on button click.
(there are edit buttons next to each product).

What would be the best method? I'm attempting to map over it, but it doesn't do me good since it returns all ids in a new array. Find()? but what testing function can I provide it to get me back the specific id (the clicked product)?
basically, I want to be able to click the button next to each product, and the ID input that pops up should be filled in with that specific product's id.

Thank you always for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select each individual `id` from objects in an array you can use `forEach`.

```
productInfo.forEach(product => () {
    console.log(product.ProductID)
})
```

Comment: why do you name the product as `e`? If it's a product then name it accordingly :)

Comment: So, forEach gives me back each individual, as it iterates a function over the array (right?). But, I want just 1 productID from the product list by clicking on the button that's adjacent to it. by click, I should be able to setProductId state to the clicked product's productId. thank you for the advice